# How I Can get the last version for each row SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to use this query to get daily costs for each campaigns, but I got the cost for only one campaign. Every campaign has the same "_sdc_sequence" but for each day there are many "_sdc_sequence". How I can get every cost for last version daily per campaign and select somes variable like day, cost, impressions and campaign? because now I get every variable of my database

"_sdc_sequence" is a unix epoch attached to the record during replication and determine the order of all the versions of a row.

I attached a picture with table. I need select only the last sequence (max _sdc_sequence)

[image: DataTable]

```
#standardSQL
SELECT row.* FROM (
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY _sdc_sequence DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] row 
FROM `adxxxxx_xxxxxxxx` t
GROUP BY day
```

thanks

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question to include sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Hi, I am adding a table in a picture

Comment: so last row for each day no matter which campaign?

Comment: Hi, I am adding a table in a picture

Comment: please confirm that you group by day only  - no matter what campaign is!

Comment: the last sequence for every campaign because I need to have the daily cost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT row.* FROM (
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY _sdc_sequence DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] row 
FROM `adxxxxx_xxxxxxxx` t
GROUP BY day, campaign
```